# How can i create an option for the user to delete an object out of the Object Collection?

Tags: php, oop

Here is my code:

```
$printcoll = $_SESSION['ObjColl'];


for($i = 0;$i < $printcoll->getlineCount();$i++){
$li = $printcoll -> getLineItem($i);
$item = $li->getItem();
if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "Bike ID - ";
} 
print $item-> getId();


if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "&nbsp Price &pound"; 

}
print $item-> getPrice();

if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "&nbsp Quantity - "; 

}

print $li->getQuantity();
echo "</br>";
```

Here is what the ObjectCollection looks like:

```
ObjectCollection Object ( [line_items_array:ObjectCollection:private] => Array ( [0] => LineItem Object ( [item:LineItem:private] => Product Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Yamaha [price] => 10000 ) [quantity:LineItem:private] => 3 ) [1] => LineItem Object ( [item:LineItem:private] => Product Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => Kawasaki [price] => 12000 ) [quantity:LineItem:private] => 7 )
```

The output of the For loop is:

Bike ID - 1  Price £10000  Quantity - 3

Bike ID - 4  Price £12000  Quantity - 7

The ObjectCollection is made up of Product objects. How do i add an option into the for loop so the user can delete a "Product" object out of the ObjectCollection class?

public function delLineItem($line_item) is the function within the ObjectCollection class. But how do i integrate that into a OPTION in the for loop because the user may or may not to delete it?

So for example, i want the output of the for loop to be :

Bike ID - 1  Price £10000  Quantity - 3       DELETE BUTTON

So if the user clicks on the delete button, it will delete that specific product out of the object collection. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to link back to your current script and create an action, for example called Delete...

Cjeck out the if block to the top, add your code for deleting the item there... Further down you will see a Delete link for activating the action...

```
$printcoll = $_SESSION['ObjColl'];

//Code for delete operation
if (is_set($_GET['delete'])) {
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    echo "Deleting $id...";
}


for($i = 0;$i < $printcoll->getlineCount();$i++){
$li = $printcoll -> getLineItem($i);
$item = $li->getItem();
if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "Bike ID - ";
} 
print $item->getId();

//Add a delete link
print "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?delete=" . $i . "'>Delete</a>";


if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "&nbsp Price &pound"; 

}
print $item-> getPrice();

if ($item instanceof Product) {
 print "&nbsp Quantity - "; 

}

print $li->getQuantity();
echo "</br>";
```

Comment: It has not worked :( I just need a simple solution to delete the object if they click the button.

Comment: No, my code wont delete anything, you will have to add that code yourself in my if-block...

Comment: $item->getId() gets the ID of the product object, not the id of the object in the Object Collection class. Im so confused haha. I Need to get the id of the object in the class, so i can delete it, not the id of the product object itself

Comment: Ahh, of course, I guess you should use $i instead in the link :) Let me know if it works and I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Yhh $i works for getting the id of the specific object. Im just working on actually deleting it in the if statement. I will let you know when i figure it out :) Thanks mate

Comment: What is ObjectCollection? if you either add a link to the definition I can try to explain how to delete an item :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68046/discussion-between-stemain2-and-richard87).